# Android Cursor - Two floats not adding if they are equal?

Tags: java, android

This is a strange problem, and I hope it has a simple solution. I have a database with encrypted values. I have created a cursor that will go through each of the entries in a table, decrypt the value from the column I need, and add the value to a variable, "total". I want the sum of all of the values in the column. Here is the code:

```
while (c.moveToNext())
      {           
            strTotal = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_TOTAL));
            strTotal = sc.decrypt(strTotal);
            total = Float.valueOf(strTotal) + total;             
      }
```

Now, here's the strange part. Let's suppose I have two values in the database: 2 + 4. After each is decrypted, it will correctly add them: 6. Now, if the values are equal: 2 + 2, for instance, the method returns "2" instead of "4". This happens even if it is off by a decimal (2 + 2.01 = 4.01, but 2 + 2 still outputs 2 for example).

Is there something I am missing here? Thanks!

EDIT:

I've changed the code around just to see if the decryption was the problem and it is still giving me the same result:

```
float total = 0;
String strTotal = "10";
while (c.moveToNext())
      {     
          try {
                //strTotal = sc.decrypt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TOTAL)));
                total = Float.valueOf(strTotal) + total;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "exception", e);
            }           
      }
```

This code is returning "10", even though there are 3 entries in the database! It looks like if two rows in the database have the same value in the KEY_TOTAL field, it is returning less results. Here is the query:

```
Cursor c = mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_TOTAL}, KEY_TYPE + "=" + t, null, null, null, null, null);
```

If I pull the db and open it with a sqlite browser, and SELECT all of the rows, I am getting 3 still, however.

Comment: just to make it clear. Do you initialize variable total = 0; before the while() runs ?

Comment: Yep, right above the while statement: float total = 0;

Comment: In my case total = Float.valueOf(strTotal) + total; working perfect. see in the decrypt statement

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, but I can't figure out why it's behaving the way it is. I have three entries, for example, each for 100. When I run it, the sum is 100. If I change one to 100, one to 101, and one to 102, I get the correct sum: 303. This means that it is at least decrypting correctly. I even tried: strTotal = ""; after each iteration and still no change...

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger to make sure the loop is executing multiple times? I'm thinking your query got turned into a SELECT DISTINCT somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the [SQLite documentation for Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (I'm not an Android developer) and I think I found your problem. The first argument to the query method is whether to select distinct rows. Since you're passing TRUE and you're only selecting one column, duplicates will be removed from the result, which is not what you want.

Changing your call to query to the following should fix your issue.

```
Cursor c = mDb.query(false, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_TOTAL},
    KEY_TYPE + "=" + t, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: This did the trick! You, sir, are my hero for the day! Something told me that I was overlooking a tiny detail...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for thrown exceptions? Especially NumberFormatException? I'm guessing there is some other logic problem that is causing the loop to exit prematurely.

Comment: Yeah, I tried catching any thrown exceptions, and the app isn't throwing any. So bizzare!

Comment: I'd check that the decrypt actually works too. You have not given us the type or the actual code that is executed here, but there has to be a problem that keeps the multiplication from working. Like decrypt returns 0.

Comment: See my edit above. I commented out the encryption and set strTotal = "10" and it still outputs the incorrect result.